# Knockoutjs: Can't wrap 'update' on checked binding, how to run js on update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using KnockoutJS 3.0, and I'm trying to create a wrapped version of the 'checked' binding. I'd like it to simply do a `$.scrollto()` after the checked value changes. I'm trying just to wrap the binding for now, without any additional behavior:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkedWithPostScroll = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //Do extra UI stuff here
        ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init(element, valueAccessor,allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

I started off wrapping "update" but found that there was no "update" for the checked binding, so I moved to wrap 'init.' But the code in init only fires once. How can I override this binding such that every time an element is checked, some javascript runs?

Here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/R9k6W/1/

I'd like the alert box to show every time an element is checked or unchecked.

A second part of the question: Is there any way to pass in an extra bit of information to the binding on top of the binding target (specifically the id of the dom element to which to scroll)? Like:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedWithPostScroll:{myObservableArray,'domElementScrollPoint'}" />
```

Thanks...
-Ben

-Ben

Comment: Please post a JSFiddle.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've found the problem corresponding to my original question, and have cleaned it up. Above now reflects that.

Answer (score 0):

A different way to achieve this is to subscribe to change notifications on the observable (or observableArray) to which you are binding. This is what I ended up with:

```
self.selectedColors = ko.observableArray();

self.selectedColors.subscribe(function (changes) {

    if (changes[0].status === 'added' && self.selectedColors().length == 1)
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#NextSection").offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }, 200);


}, null, "arrayChange");
```

Does not use a custom binding, but does work.